# Why doesn't this error instead: systemctl show 'random text here'.device

Tags: linux, systemd, qubes, showinfo

Sample:

```
[ctor@dom0 ~]$ cat nonsense 
#!/bin/bash

set -vex
systemctl show "sys-devices-virtual-block-dm\x2d0.device"
echo 
systemctl show sys-devices-virtual-block-dm\x2d0.device
echo 
systemctl show 'random text here'.device
echo
```

The following output is good when `\x2d` is not interpreted by the shell (because it's quoted):

```
[ctor@dom0 ~]$ ./nonsense 
systemctl show "sys-devices-virtual-block-dm\x2d0.device"
+ systemctl show 'sys-devices-virtual-block-dm\x2d0.device'
SysFSPath=/sys/devices/virtual/block/dm-0
Id=sys-devices-virtual-block-dm\x5cx2d0.device
Names=sys-devices-virtual-block-dm\x5cx2d0.device
Wants=lvm2-pvscan@253:0.service
Description=/sys/devices/virtual/block/dm-0
LoadState=loaded
ActiveState=active
SubState=plugged
StateChangeTimestamp=Sun 2018-09-09 15:49:14 CEST
StateChangeTimestampMonotonic=10072227
InactiveExitTimestamp=Sun 2018-09-09 15:49:14 CEST
InactiveExitTimestampMonotonic=10072227
ActiveEnterTimestamp=Sun 2018-09-09 15:49:14 CEST
ActiveEnterTimestampMonotonic=10072227
ActiveExitTimestampMonotonic=0
InactiveEnterTimestampMonotonic=0
CanStart=no
CanStop=no
CanReload=no
CanIsolate=no
StopWhenUnneeded=no
RefuseManualStart=no
RefuseManualStop=no
AllowIsolate=no
DefaultDependencies=yes
OnFailureJobMode=replace
IgnoreOnIsolate=yes
NeedDaemonReload=no
JobTimeoutUSec=30s
JobTimeoutAction=none
ConditionResult=no
AssertResult=no
ConditionTimestampMonotonic=0
AssertTimestampMonotonic=0
Transient=no
StartLimitIntervalSec=10000000
StartLimitBurst=5
StartLimitAction=none
echo 
+ echo
```

The following output is bad because the `sys-devices-virtual-block-dmx2d0.device` doesn't exist (note how the shell removed the `\`):

```
systemctl show sys-devices-virtual-block-dm\x2d0.device
+ systemctl show sys-devices-virtual-block-dmx2d0.device
Id=sys-devices-virtual-block-dmx2d0.device
Names=sys-devices-virtual-block-dmx2d0.device
Description=sys-devices-virtual-block-dmx2d0.device
LoadState=loaded
ActiveState=inactive
SubState=dead
StateChangeTimestampMonotonic=0
InactiveExitTimestampMonotonic=0
ActiveEnterTimestampMonotonic=0
ActiveExitTimestampMonotonic=0
InactiveEnterTimestampMonotonic=0
CanStart=no
CanStop=no
CanReload=no
CanIsolate=no
StopWhenUnneeded=no
RefuseManualStart=no
RefuseManualStop=no
AllowIsolate=no
DefaultDependencies=yes
OnFailureJobMode=replace
IgnoreOnIsolate=yes
NeedDaemonReload=no
JobTimeoutUSec=30s
JobTimeoutAction=none
ConditionResult=no
AssertResult=no
ConditionTimestampMonotonic=0
AssertTimestampMonotonic=0
Transient=no
StartLimitIntervalSec=10000000
StartLimitBurst=5
StartLimitAction=none
echo 
+ echo
```

The following output is bad because `random text here.device` doesn't exist:

```
systemctl show 'random text here'.device
+ systemctl show 'random text here.device'
Id=random\x5cx20text\x5cx20here.device
Names=random\x5cx20text\x5cx20here.device
Description=random\x5cx20text\x5cx20here.device
LoadState=loaded
ActiveState=inactive
SubState=dead
StateChangeTimestampMonotonic=0
InactiveExitTimestampMonotonic=0
ActiveEnterTimestampMonotonic=0
ActiveExitTimestampMonotonic=0
InactiveEnterTimestampMonotonic=0
CanStart=no
CanStop=no
CanReload=no
CanIsolate=no
StopWhenUnneeded=no
RefuseManualStart=no
RefuseManualStop=no
AllowIsolate=no
DefaultDependencies=yes
OnFailureJobMode=replace
IgnoreOnIsolate=yes
NeedDaemonReload=no
JobTimeoutUSec=30s
JobTimeoutAction=none
ConditionResult=no
AssertResult=no
ConditionTimestampMonotonic=0
AssertTimestampMonotonic=0
Transient=no
StartLimitIntervalSec=10000000
StartLimitBurst=5
StartLimitAction=none
echo 
+ echo
```

So the above two nonexistent `.device` are showing similar generic output, not really indicating that they don't exist(`Substate=dead` ?).  It's easy to forget to quote the device name and you get no error, thus thinking that's the real info for the specific `.device` that you wanted to see.

Systemd version 231 from Fedora 25 used, in dom0 of Qubes OS 4.0:

```
[ctor@dom0 ~]$ systemctl --version
systemd 231
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN
```

Why doesn't systemctl give an error (and exit code != 0) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `show` command is meant to be parsed by a computer (not an user), use the equivalent (but defined for humans) command `status`:

```
$ systemctl status 'random-text-here'.device; echo "Exit Status :$?"
● random-text-here.device
   Loaded: loaded
   Active: inactive (dead)
Exit Status :3
```